# Where can one download PartEdit a partition listing tool for Microsoft OSes?

Tags: windows, qemu, partitioning

There are many references to this tool, which seems to be an advanced fdisk-like utility for microsoft OSes, available from Microsoft.

But searching support.microsoft.com provides now download! (unlike, for instance, sleep.exe which one can find that way.)

Please, O monks of the overflowing stack, guide me on my quest?

Comment: your question is better suited for superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

anyway I figured out that I was looking for "diskpart" which I already have.

${QemuWiki} =~ s/\bpartedit\b/DiskPart/gi

Answer (score 0):

It's built in. Go to `Start` -> `Run` -> `CMD` ->`OK`, Type `PartEdit` and press  <kbd>Enter</kbd>